# How to efficiently and automatedly join video clips using short transitions?

Tags: ffmpeg, python, video-editing, melt

I am looking to join a set of video clips (with audio) using some short transitions (ideally crossfade) in a straightforward, automated and efficient way.

IE:

```
ClipA ---> ClipB --> ClipC --> ClipD
[aaaaaaaa][bbbbbbbb][cccccccc][dddddddd]
(--> indicate crossfades, not to scale!)
```

To clarify:

- by **straightforward**, ideally it would involve using 'standard' tools (ie ones that I am already familiar with such `ffmpeg`, but less well-known tools like `melt` definitely qualify, and I'm willing to explore new horizons like MoviePy)
- by **automated** I mean something that can be parameterised and put into a `python`/`shell`/etc script
- by **efficient** I mean *quick-to-encode* or minimising re-encoding

At the moment I'm using `python` and `ffmpeg` to chop up a video file already in Matroska/h264/aac using the stream copy parameter (*very fast*) based on timecodes in a text file. Then `melt` sequentially strings these clips one after the other using short luma (crossfade) transitions (*very slow due to re-encoding entire sequence*).

It seems to me that out of these long video clips only a few seconds needs to be processed and re-encoded- the transitions themselves. The rest can be copied. Is there an already-extant / intuitive way of doing this? My naïve approach would be to further chop the clips into subclips, using `melt` to create the transitions, and using the `concat` filter to glue the mess together.

Eg:

```
ClipA1 ClipA2 ClipB1 ClipB2 ClipB3 ClipC1 ClipC2 ClipC3 ClipD1 Clip D2
[aaaaaaa] + [a][b] + [bbbbbb] + [b][c] + [cccccc] + [c][d] + [ddddddd]
(+ indicates concat-ing of subclips; [x][y] indicates a short xfade from x to y)
```

However, I am reticent to charge off on what may be a fool's errand as I anticipate `melt`/`ffmpeg`-related gotchas around timing of cuts and audio synchronisation; and I don't want to miss sections of video or audio due to I-frame placement or what have you. Plus I have a feeling I am not the first person to run into this, so I am curious as to how those smarter than I have solved this- my solutions tend to the naïve as I say!

Hope this has been clear. Cheers for reading and thanks in advance!

---

For context, my intention is to reduce unedited livestreamed video game footage into an interesting / "useful" video; that is cut out the boring fluff of loading stuff up, sorting connectivity issues etc. But it is also generalisable to highlights, a montage to show progression. Since it is something that in theory will come up every time there is new footage, I have a strong interest in doing it the most efficient (proactively laziest) way.

Comment: I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30395469/ffmpeg-audio-crossfade) is what you are looking for. But still it process the whole video.

Comment: @Chamath thanks for that- yes it does incur a re-encode but it may in fact form part of the solution; see a related question I've asked: http://superuser.com/questions/931969/creating-videos-for-ffmpegs-concat-demuxer-to-avoid-a-large-re-encode

Answer (score 7):

I didn't have time to test it but this should work if you want to go with MoviePy:

```
from moviepy.editor import *

clips = [ VideoFileClip("vid1.mp4"),
          VideoFileClip("vid2.mp4"),
          VideoFileClip("vid3.mp4"), ... ]


fade_duration = 1 # 1-second fade-in for each clip
clips = [clip.crossfadein(fade_duration) for clip in clips]

final_clip = concatenate_videoclips(clips, padding = -fade_duration)

# You can write any format, in any quality.
final_clip.write_videofile("final.mp4", bitrate="5000k")
```

Comment: As I am unfamiliar with MoviePy, this is very useful- thank you! However, it incurs a transcode across the entire duration of video unfortunately; trying with 2 clips is giving a predicted ~2hr encode duration. Is this unavoidable or have I not used your sample code correctly?

Comment: @bertieb same problem here, it takes too long, did you find anything efficient ?

Answer (score -1):

Here is another way to use the Python moviePy library to create fading effect between joint video clips. Tested on windows 10 with Python 3.x. I had to first install the moviepy from Windows command prompt where the python installation directory is like so:

```
C:\Users\...\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts> pip3.7.exe install moviepy;
```

Here's the full code to use the CompositeVideoClip method for joining three short video clips with CrossFadeIn effect added:

```
from moviepy.editor import *
# video lists and play time
clip1 = VideoFileClip("part1.mp4") #30s length
clip2 = VideoFileClip("part2.mp4") #12s
clip3 = VideoFileClip("part3.mp4") #20s

# Composite video and apply CrossFadeIn effect
video=CompositeVideoClip([clip1,
                          clip2.set_start(30).crossfadein(1),
                          clip3.set_start(32).crossfadein(1.5)])

#write to file
video.write_videofile("my_composite.mp4")
```

Further readings/examples, see this https://www.journaldev.com/46531/python-moviepy-video-editing

Comment: Thank you for answering an old question, but does this add anything beyond that the other answer using MoviePy? I use MoviePy and like it, but the issue with the other answer too is that it incurs a transcode across the entire video, which is very slow

Comment: I tested the code by Zulko. When set duration time to 5 or 10 seconds, I couldn't notice any fade effect. Sending to 1 will just get you a seamless transition with no effect. Doesn't work well which motivates me to search for other solutions. The clips I used were very short so the speed is fine for merging them together and I could see the fading effect.